# PIVOT function in SQL SNOWFLAKE

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this query:

```
      SELECT *
  FROM TABLE_A
    PIVOT(MIN(DATETIME) FOR TATUS IN ('claim', 'bought', 'returned')) 
     AS P (NUMBER_ID, COUNTRY)
```

I have 10 columns in TABLE_A, when I add the PRIMARY KEY after P, so: P (NUMBER_ID, COUNTRY) - which are not the first two columns found in the table, it messes up the entire order of the table and puts those as the first two columns with the values of different columns.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?
Or how to have the 'claim', 'bought' and 'return' columns not show with quotations without having to add them in the PK?

Answer (score 1):

Let me see if I can reproduce your problem.

Staging data:

```sql
create or replace temp table source as 
select $1 id, $2 status, $3::date date, $4 rand, $5 country
from values(1, 'claimed', '2020-01-01'::date, 1.1, 'us'), (1, 'bought', '2020-01-02', 1.2, 'us'), (1, 'reverted', '2020-01-03', 1.3, 'us')
, (2, 'claimed', '2020-01-01', 1.4, 'cl'), (2, 'bought', '2020-01-02', 1.5, 'cl'), (2, 'reverted', '2020-01-03', 1.6, 'cl');
;
```

Pivoting:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM source
PIVOT(MIN(date) FOR status IN ('claimed', 'bought', 'reverted')) 
AS P(id, country)
```

[image]

That doesn't look good, indeed.

To fix it, have a sub-select that only chooses the columns to be used in the pivot:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (select id, country, status, date from source)
PIVOT(MIN(date) FOR status IN ('claimed', 'bought', 'reverted')) 
AS P(id, country, claimed, bought, reverted)
```

[image]

Please show us your sample data and desired results for further help.